# closure loop in ajax callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, closures

i have a data which were parsed from json, i display the data in a box like facebook's friends suggestion box. i want when the user click on any of the suggested users the request to be added to DB via ajax and its corresponding button disappears,everything is working just fine except the last thing(button disappears) instead the very first button in the list gets disappear, while im searching for a solution to my problem i came across something called  closure **but** i reaaly couldn't know how to implement it in my code, another problem appeared when i tried to declare the listener anonymous function inside the loop was the data get inserted in the DB multiple times 
(because its inside a loop), i know it might seems duplicated question but i  just need someone pointing me the right place to declare my inner function,

my code looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var suggest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    suggest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (suggest.readyState === 4 && suggest.status === 200) {
            var susers = JSON.parse(suggest.responseText);

            for (var i = 0; i < susers.length; i += 1) {
                var sphoto = '<div class="col-md-4 text-left  "> <div id="fimage">';
                sphoto += '<img  width="50" height="50" src="user/';
                sphoto += susers[i].activation + '/' + susers[i].pic + '"> </div>   </div>';
                var sname = '<div id="fname">' + susers[i].name + '</div>';

                // here is the form im targetting to pull informtion from
                var hidden = '<form id="fform"><input id="fnameh" name="name" type="hidden" value="' + susers[i].name + '" >';
                hidden += '<input name="id" type="hidden" value="' + susers[i].id + '" >';

                var fbutton = '<button  id="addfriend"class="btn btn-info  btn-xs pull-right text-center" type="submit" >Follow <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button></form';


                var display = document.getElementById('fsuggest');
                display.innerHTML += '<div class="scroller"><div id="fspace" > <button  type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>' + sphoto + sname + hidden + fbutton +'</div></div>'

                $('#addfriend').live('click', function(arg) {
                    return function() {
                        arg.preventDefault();
                        var data = $('#fform').serialize();
                        $.ajax({
                            data: data,
                            type: "post",
                            url: "addnew.php",
                            success: function(data) {
                             //make the text area empty
                              $('#addfriend').css("display", "none");
                                console.log(data);
                            }

                        }); // end of $.ajax

                    }(i); // end of inner function

                }); // end of click listner 



            } //end of for loop

       }
    };

    suggest.open('GET', 'box.php');
    suggest.send();
}); // end of JQUERY ready
```

Comment: ps: when i click at a any user i dont get his name in the database ,, the last name in the box gets inserted(latestname in the loop),, the last name + and the first button

Comment: can you please paste the exact snippet of the code which is not working. Also where is the code to hide the button?

Comment: this is the same code.

Comment: your loop does the same thing to the same element (the **one** with id=fsuggest) each time, so only the final iteration is present in that element

Comment: is there multiple `#addfriend` button in the page? Also what is the jquery version you are using?

Comment: @ Jaromanda X yeah i know i read i can overcome this issue using closure,, but dont know how

Comment: @user2181397 yeah i think,, because the loop creates it multiple times,, im using jquery 1.7.1

Comment: @cisco - a closure wont help bad logic - even with a closure, overwriting the SAME elements innerHTML will still result in the element having the HTML from the last loop - you need to figure out what you're trying to actually do - I'm referring to `display.innerHTML = ...` - you can't change it to `+=` - because then you'll have the problem of multiple elements with the same ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why exactly you need `closure` here. The problem seems to be with the multiple form & button with same `id`.

All these buttons have same `id` so the `forms`. So

```
$('#addfriend').live('click', function(arg) {..}) has no reference to the particular button
```

Hope this change will help

Con-cat the value of `i`with the id of the form & add an attribute `data-id=i` the button.

Beside instead of id add class `addfriend` to the button. So when this button will be clicked take the `data-id` value. Use this value to get the relevant form with id , & serialize that

```
var hidden = '<form id="fform_' + i + '"><input id="fnameh" name="name" type="hidden" value="' + susers[i].name + '" >';
hidden += '<input name="id" type="hidden" value="' + susers[i].id + '" >';


var fbutton = '<button data-id="' + i + '" id=""class=" addfriend btn btn-info  btn-xs pull-right text-center" type="submit" >Follow <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>';
```

Make below change to the click function.

Also reason of adding the event handler inside loop is not clear.

```
 $('.addfriend').live('click', function(arg) {
           arg.preventDefault();
           var getDataId = $(this).attr('data-id')  // get the data-id
            var data = $('#fform_'+getDataId).serialize(); // get relevant form
            $.ajax({
              // rest of code
           }); // end of $.ajax
           })
```

Try to use jquery version above 1.9 to use the `on` method for event delegation

Comment: var hidden = '<form id="fform_' + i + '"> ,, the double quotes after the variable i ,, thanks it worked

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes to your code.

With the new javascript, I believe most browsers support string interpolation natively (without any extra plugins or pre-compiling with babel for example) so you can just interpolate your variables within backticks ``.

Also, you seemed to be creating a form with the id of `#fform` and a button with the id of `#addfriend` for each iteration. The problem is that calling `$('#fform')` or `$('#addfriend')` will return an array with as many elements as you have users.

So I added an extra `data-suser-id` attribute with unique `id`'s on those. I am not sure the code will work because I can't actually try it and changed quite a few things but let me know if you are getting closer to your solution.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var suggest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        suggest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (suggest.readyState === 4 && suggest.status === 200) {
                var susers = JSON.parse(suggest.responseText);
                var limit = susers.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < limit; i += 1) {
                    var sphoto = `<div class="col-md-4 text-left  ">
                                    <div id="fimage">
                                        <img  width="50" height="50" src="user/${susers[i].activation}/${susers[i].pic}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>`
                    var sname = `<div id="fname">${susers[i].name}</div>`
                    // here is the form im targetting to pull informtion from
                    var hidden     = `<form id="fform" data-suser-id='${susers[i].id}'>
                                        <input id="fnameh" name="name" type="hidden" value="${susers[i].name}" >
                                        <input name="id" type="hidden" value="${susers[i].id}">`
                    var mutalusers = `</form><div id="mutal" class="text-left">
                                        <h6>
                                            <div id="fmutal">
                                                <?php echo $c = mutal(${susers[i].id}, $me, $db) ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </h6>
                                    </div>`
                    var fbutton = `<button id="addfriend" class="btn btn-info btn-xs pull-right text-center" type="submit" data-suser-id='${susers[i].id}'>Follow <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>`;
                    var display = document.getElementById('fsuggest');
                    display.innerHTML += `<div class="scroller">
                                            <div id="fspace">
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                </button>
                                                ${sphoto}
                                                ${sname}
                                                ${hidden}
                                                ${fbutton}
                                                ${mutalusers}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>`
                        // #live method is deprecated : http://api.jquery.com/live/
                    var addfriend_button = $(`#addfriend[data-suser-id=${susers[i].id}]`)
                    addfriend_button.on('click', function(arg) {
                        // return function(){
                        arg.preventDefault();
                        // the selector `#fform` doesn't seem to be unique to the current user's form data, so I added an data-attribute to make sure we are getting the correct form data
                        var data = $(`#fform[data-suser-id=${susers[i].id}]`).serialize();
                        $.ajax({
                            data: data,
                            type: "post",
                            url: "addnew.php",
                            success: function(data) {
                                //make the text area empty for the current user's `#addfriend` button
                                addfriend_button.html('done');
                                console.log(data);
                            }
                        }); // end of $.ajax
                        // }(i); // end of inner function : not sure why this inner function is necessary
                    }); // end of click listner
                } //end of for loop
                console.log(susers);
            }
        };
        var suugestFile = 'box.php';
        suggest.open('GET', suugestFile);
        suggest.send();
    }); // end of JQUERY ready
```